# Align authors center

Tags: align, positioning, author

I am new to Latex and Overleaf and I have a problem with the alignment of author section. My code is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage{subfigure,times,graphics,mathptm,epsfig,amsmath,xspace,endnotes,pifont,multirow,rotating,listings,amssymb,algorithmic,color,caption,nicefrac,adjustbox,todonotes,tabularx,mathtools, algorithmic,algorithm, soul}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\title{MESON: Facilitating Cross-Slice Communications \\ for Enhanced Service Delivery at the Edge}
\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{Konstantinos Katsaros, Vasileios Glykantzis}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Intracom Telecom, Greece\\
\{konkat, vasgl\}@intracom-telecom.com}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Panagiotis Papadimitriou, Georgios
\IEEEauthorblockA{University of Macedonia, Greece\\
\{papadimitriou, papathanail\}@uom.edu.gr}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Dimitrios Dechouniotis, Symeon Papavassiliou}
\IEEEauthorblockA{National Technical University of Athens, Greece\\
\{ddechou@netmode, papavas@mail\}.ntua.gr}
}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the output is like this[image: authorsection]

How can I align this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by making your code example compilable (a MWE).

Comment: @TeXnician is it ok now?

Comment: Yes. In conference mode the authors are inserted into a tabular environment which – according to the docs – should create the correct behavior. After some fiddling around I do not know where – using what is documented – one should get the correct behavior. Maybe somebody else will…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation "...For papers with three or less affiliations, a multicolumn format is preferred", so you might want to consider using multiple columns to be in keeping with the prescribed style (although the output does look wrong in this instance). Attaining a single column is as simple as removing the `\and` commands (these create columns), and adding addition line breaks with `\\` after each affiliation block:

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage{subfigure,times,graphics,mathptm,epsfig,amsmath,xspace,endnotes,pifont,multirow,rotating,listings,amssymb,algorithmic,color,caption,nicefrac,adjustbox,tabularx,mathtools, algorithmic,algorithm, soul}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\title{MESON: Facilitating Cross-Slice Communications \\ for Enhanced Service Delivery at the Edge}
\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{Konstantinos Katsaros, Vasileios Glykantzis}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Intracom Telecom, Greece\\
\{konkat, vasgl\}@intracom-telecom.com} \\
% \and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Panagiotis Papadimitriou, Georgios}
\IEEEauthorblockA{University of Macedonia, Greece\\
\{papadimitriou, papathanail\}@uom.edu.gr} \\
% \and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Dimitrios Dechouniotis, Symeon Papavassiliou}
\IEEEauthorblockA{National Technical University of Athens, Greece\\
\{ddechou@netmode, papavas@mail\}.ntua.gr}
}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Edit: The class documentation specifies an alternative author layout using footnote symbols to link authors and affiliations that you may want to consider. With your authors:

```
\author{
    \IEEEauthorblockN{Konstantinos Katsaros\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, Vasileios Glykantzis\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
    Panagiotis Papadimitriou\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, Georgios\IEEEauthorrefmark{2},\\
    Dimitrios Dechouniotis\IEEEauthorrefmark{3} and  Symeon Papavassiliou\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}University of Macedonia, Greece\\
    \{papadimitriou, papathanail\}@uom.edu.gr}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}University of Macedonia, Greece\\
    \{papadimitriou, papathanail\}@uom.edu.gr}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}National Technical University of Athens, Greece\\
    \{ddechou@netmode, papavas@mail\}.ntua.gr}
}
```

Output:
[image: output2]